# How to change labels's text from TS file in Angular?

Tags: angular, text, data-binding

I have a HTML file like this:

```
<div class="form-popup playerOne" id="myForm_output" dir="rtl">
  <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-container">  
    <label id="l1"><b> {{label1}} </b></label>
    <label id="l2"><b> {{label2}} </b></label>
    <label id="l3"><b> {{label3}} </b></label>
    <label id="l4"><b> {{label4}} </b></label>


    <button type="submit" class="btn " style="margin-top: 270px;" (click)="doOutput()">اعمال</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">انصراف</button> 
  </form>
</div>
```

And tried to set label's text like this in my TS file:

```
someFunc(x)
{
   if(x === 0)
    this.label1 = 'this is zero';
   if(x === 1)
    this.label1 = 'this is one';
}
```

But it doesn't work. I mean the labels wont becomming set in the program.

Comment: it should work. what do you mean by it does not work? can produce it via stackblitz?

Comment: Works perfectly fine. Here's a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-da9mtg). Check it and see what you did wrong.

Comment: @Sajeetharan: I mean the labels wont becomming set in the program.